# Stripe - Mandatory values missing from Api4 PaymentprocessorWebhook

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, stripe

A new Civi 5.66 install on WP 6.3.1 and Stripe Payment Processor 6.10-dev

All memberships (recurring or not) are Pending with no start or end date when using the test link. Payment is registered in Stripe, but I see no webhooks in CiviContribute > Payment Processor Webhooks (empty) despite trying multiple times.

Checking the Civi logs, I see this error:

`[error] ipn_payment_callback_exception`
...
`[message] => Mandatory values missing from Api4 PaymentprocessorWebhook::create: message`

New to Civi, so probably making a basic mistake! But I've looked all afternoon and not finding a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: I should add that this is only when using Stripe Checkout. Stripe (the non-checkout option) works fine.